# TypeError: Test_1.Instance is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, runtime-error

So i just started typescript from 2 days ago and so far i got into constructors, Im currently having a problem with exporting a class,
It doesnt cause an error when i use the class in the same script file but only when i export it

**The code that has the error**

```
import { Instance } from "./Test";
let X = new Instance("Hello", [3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1]);
console.log(X.name);
```

**The Error**

```
let X = new Instance("Hello", [3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1]);
        ^
TypeError: Test_1.Instance is not a constructor
```

**The Class**(another File)

```
export class Instance {

    name: string;
    Size: number[];
    Position: number[];

    constructor(Name: string, Size: number[], Position: number[]) {
        this.name = Name;
        this.Size = Size;
        this.Position = Position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the class (the last code block above) is in `./Test`? Because that code is just fine other than some style things I'd quibble about (usually you don't capitalize property names, and names that refer to arrays typically should be plural, ...). It should work. Your `export` is correct, your `import` of that export is correct, it *is* a constructor...

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem: Two files with just the minimum in them that causes the error, your `tsconfig.json`, and the details of any bundler you're using.